# Shopify API error: {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-api

```
import requests

# Replaced with my actual Shopify credentials and file information!!!
API_KEY = 'text' // using my Shopify App "API key"
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'text' // using my Shopify App "Admin API access token"
SHOP_NAME = 'text.myshopify.com' // using the root myshopify URL
file_path = r"C:\text\API-TEST-1.jpg"

url = f'https://{SHOP_NAME}/admin/api/2023-04/graphql.json'

query = """
mutation stagedUploadsCreate($input: [StagedUploadInput!]!) {
  stagedUploadsCreate(input: $input) {
    stagedTargets {
      resourceUrl
      url
      parameters {
        name
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

variables = {
    'input': [
        {
            'resource': 'IMAGE',
            'filename': 'your-image.jpg',
            'mimeType': 'image/jpeg',
            'httpMethod': 'POST',
        }
    ]
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}',
}

response = requests.post(url, json={'query': query, 'variables': variables}, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

staged_targets = data.get('data', {}).get('stagedUploadsCreate', {}).get('stagedTargets', [])

if staged_targets:
    target = staged_targets[0]
    params = target['parameters']
    upload_url = target['url']
    resource_url = target['resourceUrl']

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read()

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': str(len(file_data)),
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': ACCESS_TOKEN,
    }

    headers.update(params)

    response = requests.put(upload_url, headers=headers, data=file_data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Image uploaded successfully.')
    else:
        print('Failed to upload the image.')
        print(response.text)
else:
    print('Failed to generate upload URL and parameters.')
    print(response.text)
```

It keeps telling me this: Failed to generate upload URL and parameters. {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}

However I'm using the API key in my Shopify Apps dashboard for the app I created, and I have the permissions "write files/read files" activated. I'm also using the access token I was given for this same app. Why is it not working? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This may be a better question for shopify support. From a code standpoint, `unrecognized login or wrong password` is a pretty clear error message, and not one we can really help you resolve beyond "check to make sure your keys and tokens are correct, not malformed, and don't have extra characters or whitespace"

Comment: I am having the same issue ¿Did you find the solution? I think there is a mistake on the error description.